# How do I programmatically insert custom cells in a collection view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that is not initialized with anything. It is meant to show a grid of images. The images are loaded from the internet and I am attempting to dynamically add these images to the collection view as they are loaded.

The collection view has a custom cell that contains an image view that is given a reuse identifier.

As I understand it I can add items to a collectionView by using the following:

```
[collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:newData];
```

But what I am trying to figure out specifically is how to add a new custom cell given given an identifier and provide it with my loaded UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Create collection view object

   ```
   UICollectionView *collectionVC;
   ```
2. Set collection view in viewdidload

   ```
   collectionVC=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 94, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-133) collectionViewLayout:layout];

   [collectionVC setDataSource:self];

   [collectionVC setDelegate:self];

   UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PDetailViewCell" bundle:nil];
   [collectionVC registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

   [collectionVC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

   [self.view addSubview:collectionVC];
   ```
3. collection view delegate method

   ```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

   PDetailViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   return cell;
   }
   ```
4. Create a custom cell `PDetailViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to add new cell xCell for new item x of different type UICollectionviewCellType1, Then you need to insert the new item in the array which you used to display the collection view and write the logic in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check for new item and use your new cell type in UICollectionView.

In case of some issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't insert each individual items manually. You tell the collection view how many sections it has, how many items each section has, and what do you want to display for each item.

Be sure to check `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`.